# Working with IsolatedSTorageSettings for Windows 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I was working with windows 7 application development and trying to create the same application given on their website to create and add notes (its an app to save notes in windows phone 7).

The example has used IsolatedFileStorage to store each note. That is a new file is created everytime we create a note.

I wanted to understand how to work with IsolatedStorageSettings where instead of creating a new file for every note I could maintain a note object in the isolated storage.

Could someone point me towards some good examples/tutorials online for the same?

Thank you

Comment: You'll probably want to stick to saving a file to isolatedstorage if your saving files that have alot of data. This would perform better. I usually use IsolatedStorageSettings for smaller things like app preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to stay with IsolatedStorageFile for this kind of purposes, because it will provide better performance for large data sets in general for your app.

If you do want to switch to IsolatedStorageSettings, it is very to use as it is just a key/value pair storage. So if you represent the data part of your note as an object, you can store/retrieve it in the settings simply by assigning it a unique key.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(VS.95).aspx